# Какой правильный синтаксис для sass перечислений?

Tags: css, sass, scss

Я хочу написать след. массив урлов:

```
.Header_theme_airport
    background-image: image-set(
        url('/img/airport-1200-1x.png') 1x,
        url('/img/airport-1200-2x.png') 2x,
    )
```

В результате компиляции ошибка в синтаксисе. Скажите пожалуйста как можно это написать согласно сас синтаксиса, что бы удобно было читать. Если я все напишу в одну строку то все компилируется, но это не читабельно:(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Пока SASS не разрешает переносить аргументы функции на другую строку. Вопрос [обсуждается с 2011 года](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/216), но воз и ныне там.

За эту возможность уже [просят НЕ голосовать](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/216#issuecomment-390433189). Голосов и так много, не хватает только героя, который бы её запрограммировал.

> Dear "+1" spammers: can we please take actual steps towards resolving this instead of just adding to the noise with yet another empty comment? <...>
> It is utterly useless at solving the issue and just triggers a notification for the 91 people in here for absolutely no reason. Looks like the actual way forward is making improvements on dart-sass and the spec in collaboration with the maintainers.

Переводя коротко и вольно:

> Те, кто добавляет комментарии с `+1`, только понапрасну дёргают подписчиков этого запроса. Лучше сделайте сами что-нибудь, чтобы воплотить его в жизнь.

В ответ на запрос 2013 года [разработчик поясняет](https://github.com/sass/sass/issues/715#issuecomment-16676076):

> <..> This is something I'd like to support, but I haven't had the time to do it. It's more complicated than it seems, since the indented syntax parser is pretty crufty and weird.
>
> Буду рад поддерживать такую штуку, но у меня нет времени её создавать. Дело сложнее, чем кажется, поскольку анализатор отступов и без того заморочен и причудлив.

Comment: У меня sass синтаксис а не scss. Тут нет фиг. скобок. Тут отступы

Comment: ошибся, полностью переделал ответ

Comment: эх как жаль:( Спасибо за развернутый ответ:)